# How to get realtime like count from a picture posted by my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I'm developing an application and what I want it to do is:

1. Post a poto on the user's wall
2. Get, in realtime, the number of likes that this post will recieve

The first problem I'm having is to get the likes count based on the post-id, this is my photo upload code:

```
FB.api('/photos', 'post', {
        message: $user_submited_string,
        url:'http://example/url/image.jpg'        
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            //error handler
        } else {
           var posted_content_id = response.postid;
           console.log(posted_content_id);
        })
```

But when I put this `posted_content_id` variable into the Open Graph Debugger I won't get the number of likes in return:

```
{
  "id": "1685033176_4107146412059", 
  "from": {
    "name": "João Paulo Apolinário Passos", 
    "id": "1685033176"
  }, 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/548929_4107355417284_1018318871_s.jpg", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=4107355417284&set=a.4107146292056.1073741826.1685033176&type=1&relevant_count=7", 
  "name": "My Test App Photos", 
  "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1685033176/posts/4107146412059"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1685033176/posts/4107146412059"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
  }, 
  "type": "photo", 
  "status_type": "added_photos", 
  "object_id": "4107355417284", 
  "application": {
    "name": "My Test App", 
    "id": "178883808932511"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2013-04-10T01:20:12+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2013-04-10T01:20:12+0000"
}
```

Which does not contain the like count of my picture. So **the first question is**: how to get the like count of the image that the user inserted?

The second thing is that, after getting the number of likes, I want to rank them. To do that, I thought about storing them into a database and set a cron job to check new posts and update the rank with new posts. When I was looking how to do that I came across the "Realtime Updates" section of the Facebook Developers Documentation. But for me it's not clear if I can get this like count in real time and how. And that is **my second question**: Can I get the number of likes of an image in realtime, using native "Realtime Updates"? And if that's not possible, how to create my own counter? Extended token and cronjobs?

I'm asking this two questions in one because maybe the second question's anwser is also the first one. And the last thing I need to know: even if it's doable, doing something like that violates on someway Facebook Policies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are querying for the **Post Id**, not the **Photo Id**.

When you upload the photo, a post is also automatically published on the feed of the user.
To read the Photo id, you must use the `response.id` property.

In your example the id of the photo is `4107146412059`, you can derive it from the post id that is in the form `<user-id>_<photo-id>`, but don't count on it, since that can change in the future.

Doc on the Photo object in the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

**Real time updates:**

You can get real time push notification from Facebook when the User feed is updated:
[image]

but this would be overkill, since you'll get all the posts to the User feed, not only to your photo. Sadly, I think the only way is to poll for updates.

Other info on Real time updates: [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/managing-realtime-update-subscriptions/)